# NSIS: Adding Link to License page

Tags: hyperlink, nsis

In my installer's License page, I want to use a Hyperlink instead of text box. Link will be having the address of my webpage containing the License agreement.

I have already hid the text box, now the problem is adding the link. I want to add something like this:

click [here](http://example.com/) to read License agreement.

I tried using Linker plugin as well as NSD_createlink but in both case the installer crashes.

How can I make it work ?

**EDIT:**

I am trying to make the link of ID 1006 only.

Following is my code, now its not crashing but neither is it working.

```
; For license page.
Function LicensePageShow
nsResize::Set $mui.LicensePage.TopText 120 180 250u 200u
;LogSet on
Call GetDateTime
Pop $dt
logex::Write "$dt In LicensePageShow "

GetDlgItem $0 $HWNDPARENT 1036
ShowWindow $0 ${SW_HIDE}

GetDlgItem $0 $HWNDPARENT 1045
ShowWindow $0 ${SW_HIDE}

GetDlgItem $0 $HWNDPARENT 1035
ShowWindow $0 ${SW_HIDE}

/* Hiding default License text box */
FindWindow $R0 `#32770` `` $HWNDPARENT
GetDlgItem $R0 $R0 1000
nsResize::Set $R0 0 0 0 0
ShowWindow $R0 ${SW_HIDE}


/* The License page Text */
FindWindow $0 "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT
GetDlgItem $0 $0 1006
Linker::link /NOUNLOAD $0 "http://www.google.com"

FindWindow $R0 `#32770` `` $HWNDPARENT
GetDlgItem $R0 $R0 1038
ShowWindow $R0 ${SW_HIDE}

FindWindow $R0 `#32770` `` $HWNDPARENT
GetDlgItem $R0 $R0 1040
nsResize::Set $R0 50 80 300u 20u

System::Call '*(i,i,i,i)i.r1'
FindWindow $0 "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT
GetDlgItem $2 $0 0x40A
System::Call 'USER32::GetWindowRect(ir2,ir1)'
System::Call 'USER32::MapWindowPoints(i0,ir0,ir1,i1)'
System::Call '*$1(i.r6,i.r7)'
System::Call 'USER32::GetClientRect(ir2,ir1)'
System::Call '*$1(i,i,i.r8,i.r9)'
IntOp $9 $9 + 3 ;padding
IntOp $7 $7 - $9
GetDlgItem $2 $0 0x3EE
System::Call 'USER32::GetClientRect(ir2,ir1)'
System::Call '*$1(i,i,i.r3,i.r4)'
System::Free $1
IntOp $4 $4 - $9 ;reduce size of label
System::Call 'USER32::SetWindowPos(ir2,i,i,i,ir3,ir4,i6)'
System::Call 'USER32::CreateWindowEx(i0,t "Button",t "Let Setup modify your browser settings",i ${__NSD_CheckBox_STYLE},ir6,ir7,ir8,ir9,ir0,i666,i0,i0)i.r2'
SendMessage $0 ${WM_GETFONT} 0 0 $0
SendMessage $2 ${WM_SETFONT} $0 1

${If} $Revisit == "false" ; If its Visited for first time
${NSD_SetState} $2 1 ;check it]
${Else} ; If user clicked back button on directory page
${NSD_SetState} $2 $checkboxstate
${endIf}

/* to Reposition the checkbox */
FindWindow $R0 `#32770` `` $HWNDPARENT
GetDlgItem $R0 $R0 666
;ShowWindow $R0 ${SW_HIDE}
;nsResize::Set $R0 50 120 300 20
System::Call 'USER32::SetWindowPos(i, i, i, i, i, i, i) b ($R0, 0, 50, 210, 300, 20, 0)'


FindWindow $R0 `#32770` `` $HWNDPARENT
GetDlgItem $R0 $R0 1034
;ShowWindow $R0 ${SW_HIDE}
;nsResize::Set $R0 50 120 300 20
System::Call 'USER32::SetWindowPos(i, i, i, i, i, i, i) b ($R0, 0, 50, 150, 300, 20, 0)'


FindWindow $R0 `#32770` `` $HWNDPARENT
GetDlgItem $R0 $R0 1035
;ShowWindow $R0 ${SW_HIDE}
;nsResize::Set $R0 50 120 300 20
System::Call 'USER32::SetWindowPos(i, i, i, i, i, i, i) b ($R0, 0, 50, 170, 300, 20, 0)'

; Set transparent backgrounds.
  FindWindow $mui.LicensePage "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT
  SetCtlColors $mui.LicensePage 0xFFFFFF transparent
  !insertmacro SetTransparent $mui.LicensePage 1040
  !insertmacro SetTransparent $mui.LicensePage 1000
  ;!insertmacro SetTransparent $mui.LicensePage 1006
  !insertmacro SetTransparent $mui.LicensePage 1034
  !insertmacro SetTransparent $mui.LicensePage 1035
  !insertmacro SetTransparent $mui.LicensePage 666
  ; Refresh controls.
  Call RefreshParentControls
GetDlgItem $0 $HWNDPARENT 1045
ShowWindow $0 ${SW_HIDE}
FunctionEnd
```

Answer (score 1):

Long story short: Linker plug-in works fine, quoted code not.

What are you trying to do with this code?

```
GetDlgItem $2 $0 0x3EE
System::Call 'USER32::GetClientRect(ir2,ir1)'
System::Call '*$1(i,i,i.r3,i.r4)'
System::Free $1
IntOp $4 $4 - $9 ;reduce size of label
System::Call 'USER32::SetWindowPos(ir2,i,i,i,ir3,ir4,i6)'
System::Call 'USER32::CreateWindowEx(i0,t "Button",t "Let Setup modify your browser settings",i ${__NSD_CheckBox_STYLE},ir6,ir7,ir8,ir9,ir0,i666,i0,i0)i.r2'
SendMessage $0 ${WM_GETFONT} 0 0 $0
SendMessage $2 ${WM_SETFONT} $0 1
```

0x3EE Hex is 1006 Dec - are you trying to resize this control, reposition or what?

This code is definitely wrong (when I used it my installer has crashed).

You should NOT use CreateWindowEx messages in NSIS (there are many troubles with it), always create control with ResHacker.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your script (snippet is enough).
I think you made something wrong - why do you need to hide a text box? And which one?

Correct syntax of this plug-in is:

```
FindWindow $0 "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT
GetDlgItem $0 $0 1006
Linker::link /NOUNLOAD $0 "http://www.unsigned-softworks.sk/"
```

where **1006** is ID of your control which is transformed into link.
This control is usually text (STATIC).

Did you add your own control on dialog (e.g. using ResHacker) or which control id are you trying to switch into link?